# Look up multiple rows

Tags: excel, formula, lookup

I have an Excel spreadsheet like this:

[image: SO24544684 question example]

and wish to access the entire address by buyer's name.

For example, for `LELY TANIA WIJAYA` I am able to get `SUTERA JELITA 2 NO. 29` (the first line of the address) by using VLOOKUP but then I find it difficult to get the second and third rows (`RT 002 ...` etc).

Is there a formula or other easy way to get the whole address?

Answer (score 1):

Switch to the INDEX/MATCH combination. If `LELY TANIA WIJAYA` is in A1 then `MATCH("LELY TANIA WIJAYA",A:A,0)` will return `1` (the first row in ColumnA) to feed into the INDEX function:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH("LELY TANIA WIJAYA",A:A,0))
```

to return the contents of the cell in the corresponding row in the B column. For the next two rows:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH("LELY TANIA WIJAYA",A:A,0)+1)
```

and

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH("LELY TANIA WIJAYA",A:A,0)+2)
```